# Eliminate space in a string found on the same line that a specified string

Tags: python, string, search, replace, position

I'm new to Python and this would be my first coding. I saw topics with similar problems to the one I am trying to resolve, but since I am new, I can't really figure where to go (hot to adapt it for what I need) from those topics so I took a chance to write my question below.

The question is: I have a text file containing multiple occurrences like the one shown below. In the occurrences, the characters before the > do not change from one occurrence to the other and the other characters change:

> STMTTRN>
>
> TRNTYPE>DÉBIT
>
> DTPOSTED>20 131 116 170 000
>
> TRNAMT>-8,63
>
> FITID>201311181652559
>
> NAME>LA FABRIQUE ARHOMA MONTREAL QC H
>
> MEMO>5719: LA FABRIQUE ARHOMA MONTREAL QC H2K1T4 CAN
>
> /STMTTRN>"

Basically, I want to eliminate the spaces between the numbers on the line where `<DTPOSTED>` appears. How can I do that?

I got a basic algoritm, but i don't really know how to write it in Python. I think the solution would be:

> Until the end of the document, do the following: Find the position
>   (line and column) of "" On the same line and after the word
>   "", erase all space charaters until you read an enter (/n)
>   sign Pass to the next line

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Your example does not contain the sequence "". Can you update it to show us?

Comment: Sorry. The sequence "" is "DTPOSTED>"

Answer (score 0):

Sample input file `inp.txt` contains:

```
STMTTRN>
TRNTYPE>DEBIT
DTPOSTED>20 131 116 170 000
TRNAMT>-8,63
FITID>201311181652559
NAME>LA FABRIQUE ARHOMA MONTREAL QC H
MEMO>5719: LA FABRIQUE ARHOMA MONTREAL QC H2K1T4 CAN
/STMTTRN>"

STMTTRN>
TRNTYPE>DEBIT
DTPOSTED>20 131 116 170 000
TRNAMT>-8,63
FITID>201311181652559
NAME>LA FABRIQUE ARHOMA MONTREAL QC H
MEMO>5719: LA FABRIQUE ARHOMA MONTREAL QC H2K1T4 CAN
/STMTTRN>"
```

The Code is,

```
def eliminate():
    ## read From the Text file.
    with open('inp.txt', 'r') as fp:
        ## Read the first line.
        ## Since the size of the file is not known
        ## reading the file line by line.
        line = fp.readline()

        while line:
            ## if the line is not Empty.
            if line:
                ## if "DTPOSTED" found in the line read.
                if 'dtposted' in line.lower():
                    ## Get the integer part alone.
                    _, value = line.split('>')
                    ## Remove the spaces between the integer value.
                    ## and print it to the console.
                    print ''.join(value.split())

            ## Reading the next line from the file.
            line = fp.readline()


eliminate()
```

`OUTPUT` is,

```
20131116170000
20131116170000
```

Comment: Thanks Siva Cn,

Can you provide me with further details:
- Is it possible to comment your program in the view of a very novice programmer? 
- Also, is it possible to explain the functions you are using (_dict, ele.split, etc.)

Also:
- I only want to remove the space characters on the line where 'DTPOSTED' appears and only the spaces after this sequence. It appears on multiple lines in my document;
- My data is in a text file, so I need to open the text file since I will want to run the program for many files.

Thanks

Comment: @ Siva Cn Thanks. It makes me realize I forgot to mention one thing. This is almost what I want except that I need the result to be written back at the same place in the text file (but without the spaces) and this text file to be saved under a new name. Thanks again. Basically I am using a software that is suppose to read the file but can't because of the space between the numbers (sorry I should have explained this before).

Answer (score 0):

```
#1 - open the file, get the content as a unique string including \n 
with open("inp.txt", "r") as f:
    a = "".join(f.readlines())

#2 - extract the numbers after keyword "DTPOSTED>"
numbers = a.split('DTPOSTED>')[-1].split('\n')[0]

#3 - save the parts of the file comming before and after DTPOSTED>
before, after = a.split(numbers)

#4 - remove spaces
numbers = "".join(numbers.split()).strip()

#5 - write output
with open("inp.modified.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(before + numbers + after)
```